# Foreign key or boolean value in database

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relationship

Let's say I have a database with two tables, User and Store.
Lets make the rules:

1. A User must belong to one Store
2. A Store may have one or more Users

A store though, may have a store manager. What is the best approach for this?
Adding a 'is_store_manager' boolean column at the Users table, or create a foreign key called something like `manager_user_fk` at the Store table? I guess that would create a many to many relationship though, which would be bad, but it would be a solid constraint to select a user I think. What would be the best approach?

Comment: I personally recommend adding a table called `Role` and a link table called `UserRole`.  The flag based approach is definitely not going to scale, you may for example have a deputy store manager as well in larger stores. Having the link table `UserRole` will allow for a user to have multiple roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a fk on the `Store`.  It is somewhat redundant and will make some future SQL queries harder.

You could add another table, `UserType` with the `Manager`, and `Non-Manager` types.  You'd then add a fk on the Users table pointing to the UserType.

**Edit:**

If you wanted a user to be allowed multiple roles, you'd need another `join table`:

Let's call the previous table table `Role`, instead of `UserType`, and add another table, `UserRole` that is a join between `User` and `Role` (it has only 2 columns: a foreign key to `User`, and a foreign key to `Role`.  With this setup, you wouldn't have any fk on the `User` table, as this join table would hold all the information about the relationship.  A user could have as many roles as you like then.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. But what if I want a user to have both the role "store_manager" and "system_admin" or something? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the accepted solution which only allows a user to be of one type you can use what I've been doing to replace boolean status fields. Create a table called `UserManager` with a primary key also being a foreign key to User.

Any user with an entry in `UserManager` is a manager. To get the managers you just join the User table with the `UserManager`. This also lets you store more meta data (i.e. you could store when the user became a manager etc).

Then if you want an `AdminUser` table, you do the same thing. Any user in the AdminUser table is also an admin. You can have a user be both (or none, or one). Along with storing more meta data about the type.

Comment: That sounds quite smart, also as you noticed for storing more meta data. Thanks for your addition!

Comment: It's not that dissimilar to the accepted answer, except your types aren't dynamic. You can store meta data on the accepted answer also by having a through table. But the meta data you can store will have to be the same types. If you have a multitable approach then you can have different types of meta data.